# What is known about the following series?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

For $k\in{\mathbb Z}^2$ write $|k|=\sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}$ for the euclidean norm. Then let $g(k)=gcd(k_1,k_2)$.
For $s\in\mathbb C$ let
$$
D(s)=\sum_{\substack{k\in{\mathbb Z}^2}\\ k\ne 0}\frac{|k|}{g(k)}e^{-s|k|}.
$$
This sum converges for $\mathrm{Re}(s)>0$. Does this function extend analytically beyond that line? If so, does it satisfy a functional equation? Are the poles, their residues and the zeros of the function   known? (location and order)

Comment: How do you want your gcd of negative numbers? Always positive?

Comment: Is $gcd(k_1,0)=k_1$?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე The sum is (anti-)symmetric w.r.t. $k_1\leftrightarrow-k_1$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: the definition of the greatest common divisor can be found in the first line of the Wikipedia article "Greatest Common Divisor".

Comment: You probably already know this, but worth making explicit:  Group all the terms with the same GCD, call it $d$.  Then $(k_1,k_2)=(md,nd)$ with $GCD(m,n)=1$.  The series on $d$ is a convergent geometric series, so the function can also be written as $\sum_{(m,n)=1}\frac{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}}{\exp(s\sqrt{m^2+n^2})-1}$.